# is there an event that has the same bubbling as a onmouseleave but for oncontextmenu?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

(EDIT: ***is there an event that has the same bubbling as a onmouseleave but for oncontextmenu?***)

This program is complex because it exchanges functions/code between `iframes`. However that isn't my problem. My problem is that I have a large amount of divs that are loaded into the document via xml, php, and ajax. Each div has a `oncontextmenu` event setup. Each div has an auto incrementing id set when the php echos the contents back via ajax. As you can see, each div has many other elements inside. 
***My problem is that the script doesn't give the id when I click on the image or other elements inside the div.***
 All in all I want to get the id when I click on the div or any elements inside it. If possible, could you explain a event capture/bubble solution? Here is that code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xml/birds.xml');
    foreach($xml->bird as $bird)
    {
        $images = explode(",",$bird->image);
        echo '<div class=\'birdContainers\' id="'.$bird->id.'">';
        echo '<span class="birdName">'.$bird->name.'</span>';
        echo '<img class="thumbImage" src="images/'.$images[0].'">';
        echo $bird->fourLetterCode;
        echo '<div class="birdButtons"><input type="button" class="edit" onclick="alert(\'open popup for editing see line 10 inside php/getBirds.php\');" value="Edit"><input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" onclick="alert(\'delete see line 10 inside php/getBirds.php\');"></div>';
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

Here is the javascript which adds the oncontextmenu event to all the divs:

```
$('#birds').load('php/getBirds.php', function(){
            var birdContainers = document.getElementsByClassName('birdContainers');
            for(var i = 0; i != birdContainers.length; i++)
            {
                if (birdContainers[i].addEventListener) {
                    birdContainers[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {var mouseX = e.clientX || e.pageX; var mouseY = e.clientY || e.pageY; window.parent.document.getElementById('menu').style.left = mouseX+20+'px'; alert(e.target.id); window.parent.document.getElementById('menu').style.top = mouseY+100+'px'; window.parent.document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'block'; this.style.borderColor = '#3B87FF'; e.preventDefault();}, true);
                    birdContainers[i].addEventListener("dblclick", function(event){openBird(this.id);}, true);
                    birdContainers[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){this.style.borderColor = '#3B87FF';}, true);
                } else if (birdContainers[i].attachEvent) {
                    birdContainers[i].attachEvent("dblclick", function(event){openBird(this.id);}, true);
                    birdContainers[i].attachEvent("click", function(event){this.style.borderColor = '#3B87FF';}, true);
                    birdContainers[i].attachEvent('contextmenu', function(e) {var mouseX = e.clientX || e.pageX; var mouseY = e.clientY || e.pageY; window.parent.document.getElementById('menu').style.left = mouseX+20+'px'; window.parent.document.getElementById('menu').style.top = mouseY+100+'px'; window.parent.document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'block'; this.style.borderColor = '#3B87FF'; e.preventDefault();}, false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is the function that runs when the button inside my custom contextmenu is running:

```
<div id="menu">
    <input type="button" value="Open" onclick="document.getElementById('browse').contentWindow.openBird(i need to put the id variable here of the element clicked on when the oncontextmenu event was/is fired.);">
    </div>
```

I hope you understand what I'm asking. If not post a comment below. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you mixing jquery style with plain javascript, more consistency could be helpful to understand your issue

Comment: that is the actual code used. Jquery saves me a lot of javascript code.

Comment: I only use jquery for ajax, fading, sliding, and such. But for nothing that I can easily do in Javascript

Comment: But why are you not using jQuery for your event handlers in that loop? (Sure you don't *need* jQuery for that - or anything - but given you already have it loaded why would you deliberately avoid it?)

Comment: I need(ed) the practice of coding with javascript event listeners.

Comment: i'd like to know the real code. I know that jquery is easy. I want to know the hard way before I rely on something easy. What if I someday need to do this in javascript? I learn as I code.

Comment: Learning is fine, but you must first learn to be consistent, plus we are try to bring some valid criticism to your code

Comment: I try to put this minimal example that would return the id of the element [here (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/nsh9wyg1/)

Comment: thank you all. thank you for the fiddle as well. :-D

Comment: is there an event that has the same bubbling as a onmouseleave but for oncontextmenu?

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu the event _does_ bubble. // With the given code it is quite hard to understand what you actually want to achieve resp. what your problem is. I’d suggest you try getting it to work using jQuery first – after you have done that and thereby proven that what you want to achieve is actually possible, then you can still try to implement it yourself if you want/need to.